# Is there any way to know the RAM of an Android phone?

Tags: ram

I bought a Spice Stellar Jazz Mi-353. It tells me that it has 116MB of RAM, but it is supposed to be 256MB. Is there a way to check how much RAM my device physically has before deciding to get it replaced?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app that tells you what hardware your device has.

There are a lot of apps like this and here you have some examples: [Antutu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antutu.tester&hl=en), [Android Hardware Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dama.hardwareinfo&hl=en), [Quadrant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard&hl=en).